# C#- How to sum up specific rows in mysql via selected item in combo box?

Tags: mysql, database, combobox, selection

I have database with column product and price, my column contains identical product but different price.

```
product   | price
productA  | 20
productA  | 40    
productB  | 50
productB  | 10
```

I have button, text box and combo box, if I select a product in combo box example productA and click the button add, I want only the ProductA will be added.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvMain.Rows.Clear();
            List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect("select * from sales where product like '" + comboTotal.Text + "'");
            for (int i = 0; i < detailList.Length; i++)
            {
                dgvMain.Rows.Add(detailList[i][0], detailList[i][1], detailList[i][2], detailList[i][3]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvMain.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRowHeaderCell cell = dgvMain.Rows[i].HeaderCell;
                cell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
                dgvMain.Rows[i].HeaderCell = cell;
            }

            string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;password='';database=cashieringdb;";
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            string sql = "select sum(price group by" + comboTotal.Text + ") from sales";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            txtSum.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";
        }
```

I have an exception somewhere here:

```
string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;password='';database=cashieringdb;";
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            string sql = "select sum(price group by" + comboTotal.Text + ") from sales";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            txtSum.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";
```

Comment: Im using windows form

Comment: I honestly don't know what I am doing :D